# Which one is valid: $ 2\cos((a+b)/2)<2$ or $ 2\cos((a+b)/2)\leq2$?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Which one is valid: $ 2\cos((a+b)/2)<2$ or $ 2\cos((a+b)/2)\leq2$? I need this to be true for my proof.

Answer (score 3):

$2\cos \theta \leq 2(1)$ for any angle $\theta$, even if $\theta = (a+b)/2$

We need $\leq 2$ because then if $\theta = 0 + 2k\pi$, $\,k\in \mathbb Z,\;$ then $\cos(\theta) = 1$, in which case, $2\cos(\theta) = 2$.

Comment: As simple as that. +1

Comment: well, there goes that proof

Comment: wait never mind, it still works

Comment: Glad to hear that, @jack.